# MySQL Error 1064

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code in `Oracle`, but putting it in `MySQL` i get an error.

SQL query: Documentation

```
            Select idan
            From Certificare
            Having count(idav)=3
            Group by idan
            LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group by {idan}
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4 strong text`

Comment: Try putting your GROUP BY before HAVING

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` goes before `HAVING`, that's why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Select `idan`
From `Certificare`
Group by `idan`
Having count(`idav`)=3
LIMIT 0, 25
```

`GROUP BY` should come before `Having`